# php echo/print crashes trying to output value

Tags: php, xml, echo, large-data

This is on a Ubuntu 14 server running php 5.6

I have a script that generates a very large amount of xml into a variable, which we then want to dump to a browser page.  Like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($tempcatalog));
$catalog = MakeCatalog();
echo $catalog;
```

"very large" in this instance is 2,772,808 characters.

This is a very old application (circa 2003) that we use once per year, usually with no trouble.  This year, instead of the xml dump we get a white page.  It is NOT the largest catalog we've produced, but previously it was on Ubuntu 12/php 5.3 (FWIW). Using a debugger, I have verified that $catalog does get set to the correct contents. Executing echo $catalog; crashes the script.

The php error log reports nothing.  The apache error log reports nothing. Considering that perhaps it was a memory issue, I increased php's memory allocation from 256 to 512MB, but there was no difference. Using print instead of echo makes no difference.

Ideas?

Comment: Echoing class object would only make sense if there is `__toString()` method in this class. Is there a one in your class, or you forgot to call some method on `$catalog`?

Comment: It's not an object, just a simple - but very large - text variable. Very old web site. Really no objects are used much.

Comment: What's `$tempcatalog`? Shouldn't you do `strlen()` on `$catalog`?

Comment: Indeed!  I provided the first two lines for context not thinking they'd matter, but it seems that it does.  I swapped lines 2 & 3 and used $content for the header, and now I am getting output.  This didn't matter previously, but apparently it does now in php5.6.  I'll continue and see if it really solves or just kicks the can down the road.

Comment: Use ajax to get this file by parts. 
Save needed output in file or somewhere you what and read it chunk by chunk.